# How do I read the media-type attribute from xsl output using Java EE?

Tags: xslt, jaxb, xslt-2.0, mime-types

I using XSLT to transform XML to other content, in this case JSON.  I set the MIME using the `<xsl:output method="text" media-type="application/json" encoding="UTF-8"/>` tag.

I transform XML into JSON using saxon9.

```
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslUrl));
ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(baos);
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlStream), new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(dataOut)));
String output = baos.toString();
```

---

How can I also read the MIME as "application/json"?

Comment: Do you expect to read out that `media-type` setting from the stylesheet's source code? Or do you want to read out it from the compiled stylesheet (i.e. using Saxon's APIs)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I want to read it from the compiled stylesheet using saxon.

Comment: I think http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/PreparedStylesheet.html#getDeclaredSerializationProperties-- should allow you that so from your `transformer` you would need to try along the lines of `((net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl)transformer).getUnderlyingXsltExecutable().getUnderlyingCompiledStylesheet().getDeclaredSerializationProperties().getProperty('media-type')`. Maybe there are easier ways, Micheal Kay for sure can tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method to call to grab the MIME from the xsl:output media_type.

```
String mime = transformer.getOutputProperty(OutputKeys.MEDIA_TYPE);
```

You can then act accordingly, which in my case is to setContentType for the HttpServletResponse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't necessarily. For example, if the output is written to a file in filestore, then most operating systems don't allow the media type to be captured in the file metadata, so it will be lost.

The only exception is when the output is written to a destination that does capture the media type, for example an HTTP response. In this case, with luck, the media type will be found among the HTTP headers.

Certainly a ByteArrayOutputStream does not capture any information about media type.

Comment: If I use a different Result implementation (DOMResult, JAXBResult, SAAJResult, SAXResult, StAXResult) rather than StreamResult, might I have a better chance.  BTW, I set the HTTP response header in my implementation with "text/xml" as default.  Since I can't read the transform property, I pass that default incorrectly.

Comment: Since I am sending the result over HTTP and can set the response type in the header.  I found the method from Transformer class to grab what the xsl:output set it to.